# QToolBar Extend Button

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QToolBar` (a) inside of a `QToolbar` (b), followed by a few `QWidgets` (x) in (a)
Looks a bit like this:

> |xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|b-----------------|xxxxxxx|

(b) is a toolbar which fills with bookmarks (`QToolButton`'s). When the main toolbar (a) fills completely with bookmarks, I will see a >> extend button that is unclickable, and the new bookmarks are disappearing, though I can test and see that they are being created.

Any ideas on how to get this extend button to work correctly?

Comment: You need to post some code in order to get relevant answer. I'm a bit suspicious whether a QToolbar inside a QToolbar is a good idea, I don't even see the rationale behind that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use nested toolbars, it isn't a good idea. Instead use a `QMainWindow`, and add multiple toolbars to the window. This will allow the users to move them around, unlike adding a toolbar directly to a widget.

Example web-browser with hard-coded bookmarks: (note, don't do bookmarks like this in production code)

[image]

**win.h**

```
#ifndef _WIN_H_
#define _WIN_H_

#include <QtGui>
#include <QtWebKit>

class TestWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        TestWindow();


    private slots:
        void loadUrl(const QString& url);

    private:
        QWebView* mView;
        QSignalMapper* mUrlMap;
        Q_DISABLE_COPY(TestWindow)
};

#endif
```

**win.cpp**

```
#include "win.h"

TestWindow::TestWindow() :
    QMainWindow(),
    mView(new QWebView()),
    mUrlMap(new QSignalMapper(this))
{
    setCentralWidget(mView); // Takes ownership

    mView->load(QUrl::fromUserInput("http://qt-project.org/doc/"));

    connect(mUrlMap, SIGNAL(mapped(const QString&)), this, SLOT(loadUrl(const QString&)));

    QToolBar* tools = addToolBar("Tools");
    tools->addAction(mView->pageAction(QWebPage::Back));
    tools->addAction(mView->pageAction(QWebPage::Forward));
    tools->addAction(mView->pageAction(QWebPage::Stop));
    tools->addAction(mView->pageAction(QWebPage::Reload));

    QToolBar* bookmarks = addToolBar("Bookmarks");
    QAction* bkmkQtDoc = bookmarks->addAction(tr("Qt Documentation"));
    QAction* bkmkBbc = bookmarks->addAction(tr("BBC News"));

    connect(bkmkQtDoc, SIGNAL(triggered(bool)), mUrlMap, SLOT(map()));
    connect(bkmkBbc, SIGNAL(triggered(bool)), mUrlMap, SLOT(map()));

    mUrlMap->setMapping(bkmkQtDoc, "http://qt-project.org/doc/");
    mUrlMap->setMapping(bkmkBbc, "http://www.bbc.co.uk/");

}


void TestWindow::loadUrl(const QString& url)
{
    mView->load(QUrl::fromUserInput(url));
}
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include <QtGui>
#include "win.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    TestWindow win;

    win.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

**test.pro**

```
QT += core gui webkit
SOURCES=test.cpp win.cpp
HEADERS=win.h
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer I was looking for, from the QToolBar Class Reference: "When a QToolBar is not a child of a QMainWindow, it looses the ability to populate the extension pop up with widgets added to the toolbar using addWidget(). Please use widget actions created by inheriting QWidgetAction and implementing QWidgetAction::createWidget() instead."